# Problems With Print Output in rdlc report

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a vb.net application developed in VS 2008.  The application uses Microsoft ReportViewer for viewing/printing rdlc reports.  Everything worked as intended for a long time.  I work in city government and we (finally) upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 7.  Everything still works fine on my computer, but not most of my users are getting very large right margins on their reports.  The font does not appear to have changed.  It happens when they preview and print, but not when they export (to pdf for example).  I wondered if it could be a printer driver problem, but we all seem to have the same drivers installed.  What could be going on?  The reports still work on my computer (with VS 2008 installed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running report on Internet Explorer try to toggle Compatible Mode from Tools menu.

Comment: I am not using Internet Explorer.  I am running it in a Windows Forms application in the WinForms ReportViewer.  I have just discovered that it is fine on one of my users computers, but not on at least most of the other computers.

Comment: Some of the "new" computers in our office are new and some are old machines that were simply upgraded.  I have discovered that the problem is only on the upgraded machines.  Our help desk insists there should be no difference in the setups of the two types of machines.

Comment: check reportviewer version on both machines

Comment: The ReportViewer versions are the same.